# How to create multiple content source for a webapplicaiton hosting HSNC.

Tags: search, searchserviceapplication, content-source

I have a SharePoint farm with one web application 
That web application have hundreds of host name site collections.

web app: rootsite.sp.xyz.com

Host site collection: account.sp.xyz.com, finance.sp.xyz.com etc.

On search service I have one content source for SharePoint web app called rootsite.sp.xyz.com
I am trying to create multiple content source for that web app. 
I tried creating the new content source and adding some HNSC on the start addresses and it fails. 
How do i create multiple content sources for this one web app(if possible) ?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is one of the limitations of Search content Source. I am sure you get this error when you trying to create a separate Content Source for the HNSC.

> This URL is part of a host header SharePoint deployment and the search
>   application is not configured to crawl individual host header sites.
>   This will be crawled as a part of the host header Web application if
>   configured as a start address.

Content Source is based on Web Application URL and make sure root site collection should be there.

check this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a044f925-d3c9-4f79-bada-d8c82fe07c3d/create-a-content-source-for-only-one-hnsc-site-collection?forum=sharepointsearch

Comment: Yes, that is the error I get. The problem I am having is the web application is too big and crawling takes forever. I was hoping there might be some kind of work around like adding exception or something on each content source.